# How to get value from an input field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I tried .value , .textContent , innerText .... But nothing worked....
Below is my html

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input').value
var button = document.getElementById('submit')
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(input) /// Output is always blank
})
```

```html
<div class="input-section">
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter the word">
  <button id="submit">Find</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Also for the future, never call anything in a form "submit". If you want to submit the form using script you will not be able to unless you rename the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is blank is because, you're initializing the `input` variable with the initial value inside input, i.e. nothing.

When you click the button, you want the "current" value of input, which means that you'd have to find value on each button click.

Do it like this :

```js
var button = document.getElementById('submit')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  console.log(input);
})
```

```html
<div class="input-section">
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter the word">
  <button id="submit">Find</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the `value` property when the event fires, not before it.

```
let input = document.getElementById('input'); 
let button = document.getElementById('submit');
button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    console.log(input.value);
})
```